# Java applet doesn't fully refresh

Tags: java, applet

I've been working on a game that's played in a java applet. It all works fine, until you try to refresh the page. It often seems to 'keep' the applet it used so far, and relaunches the game in the same applet. A new process is not created, and the ram usage shoots up (~250mb instead of ~140mb), and the same console is used for the applet. The drawing process is also quite laggy; it often skips about 0.5 seconds of frames before drawing again.

It only sometimes completely refreshes the applet; a new process is created (as seen in Windows' task manager), a new console opens, it uses less ram; it just starts from scratch again.

As I experience issues when it reuses the applet, I would like to force it to create the new process every time I refresh. Is there a way to do that? Or can I somehow fix the issues when it doesn't completely refresh?

The game I'm working on can be seen at http://patrickdev.nl/galaxy048/. Once it runs, press 'f' to toggle the fps and memory details.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to be careful, posting a link to such a cute and fun demo.  I got to the 'Black Widows' level before, ..wait, what was the question?  Oh yeah.  I refreshed the applet and it went back to the beginning of the game, ..but, soon locked up thereafter.  The memory went up, but I would not worry about that before `OutOfMemoryError` - GC should take care of it.  Is it running some high-priority threads?  +1 for thinking to provide a link to the problem applet, and for making it such fun to visit.  :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I don't directly worry about the memory going up, it's just a side effect of the (imo) underlying issue. It's shame that the performance goes down when this occurs. And no,  it doesn't do much with threads altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applets support a parameter that force it to run the applet in a new jvm. This also works after refreshing the page, and is exactly what I was looking for - it starts from scratch. Just add this parameter to your applet tag:

`<param name="separate_jvm" value="true" />`

More information at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#SEPARATE_JVM

Comment: Good work.  Glad you got it sorted. :)  (Wonders) Now, can I get in a few games before mum tells me to go to bed..?